# get Firebase object name value in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, firebase

I need to use a Firebase Object name as parameter for the ui-router inside a `ng-repeat`.

I specify that fetching the favorite property as a Firebase array isn't an option.

**OBJECT STRUCURE:**

[image]

Is it possible to use the object name as a property inside a `ng-repeat`? As object name I mean for example `-K7YRDY2SP-kTN6...`

I need to do something like this:

**CODE:**

```
<div ng-repeat="fav in favs = (current.favorites)" 
     ui-sref="app.show({'itemId':OBJECT_NAME})"> 

     Name: {{fav.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in favs = (current.favourites)">
  Name: {{key}} <br/>
  Value: {{ value }}
</div>
```

Look it up in [angular's office docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties)

EDIT

Added a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cattails27/o1avc395/)

Comment: This is not a valid solution unfortunately. If I use `ui-sref="app.show({'itemId':key})"` , it outputs 0,1,2, ... not `-K7Y...`

Comment: thats strange, may I know what does the `key` and the `value` output respectively?

Comment: Sure, thank you for your help. The `key` values output 0,1,2,3 .. and the `value` output the content of each of the objects inside the favorite object, so i can use `value` like I was using `fav` in the code I posted in my question.

Comment: let me setup a jsfiddle and get back to you

Comment: @fbid checkout the fiddle and let me know

Comment: Yes usually the (key,value) is the working solution I would have used too, but in my actual case I'm using three-way data binding to keep the local `current` object in sync with Firebase, so I suspect the different behavior has something to do with it.